# How to recover the views.py file in django?

Tags: python, django, frameworks, django-views

I am using Django on Linux and am currently completing the tutorial, but a case of human error occurred. I accidentally deleted the `views.py` file (in tutorial is in the polls directory) and it would really help if anyone knew a way to reinstall the files, or if it is even necessary in the first place. I'm new to Django, so please keep that in mind. Thank you.

Comment: Use source control

Answer (score 1):

The views.py doesn't contain anything until you write it. If you hadn't written anything yet, then just create a new empty file and call it views.py.

In future, you should always use source control.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you https://github.com/wibiti/uncompyle2

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48211/free-python-decompiler-that-is-not-an-online-service/7474393#7474393) on uncompyle2 for some other comments.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of getting back the files. They are deleted.

You could try a program that scans for deleted files, but don't count on it.

Source control and frequent backups are the best methods of preventing this problem in the future.